# Why is this showing '"_Name_".__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given'?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am VERY new to python, I just wanted to make a calculator with a GUI for personal use. I used this zetcode website for an intro to wxPython, and immediately got an error when I tried to run this specific program. Can anyone help me please?

This is the program:

```
import wx
class Frame(wx.Frame):
  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.CalcUI()
  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='AlarmApp')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(5, 5))
        my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Create Alarm', pos=(5, 55))

        self.Show()
    def  CalcUI(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        file = wx.Menu()
        fileItem = fileMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit', 'Quit Application')
        menubar.Append(file, '&File')
        self.setMenuBar(menubar)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, fileItem)
        self.SetSize((200,100))
        self.SetTitle('Menu')
        self.Centre()
    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex =  Frame(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
                  
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\adam\Documents\Adam\Python\time.py", line 39, in <module>
    `main()`
  File "C:\Users\adam\Documents\Adam\Python\time.py", line 34, in main
    `ex =  Frame(None)`
TypeError: Frame.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared **init** twice. The second declaration obscures the first.

Thus the effective variant is:

```
def __init__(self):
```

This method implicitly takes one argument. You are calling:

```
ex = Frame(None)
```

...which means that __init__ receives two arguments - hence your error.

You probably mean:

```
ex = Frame()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I will definitely learn more of this, but what about the attributes of 'self'?

Answer (score 0):

@DarkKnight has provided the answer to your question, this answer attempts to give you, at least, a working piece of code to play with.

```
import wx
class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Frame, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.CalcUI()

    def  CalcUI(self):
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        filem = wx.Menu()
        fileItem = filem.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit', 'Quit Application')
        menubar.Append(filem, '&File')
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(5, 5))
        my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Create Alarm', pos=(5, 55))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, fileItem)
        self.SetSize((200,100))
        self.SetTitle('Menu')
        self.Centre()
    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex =  Frame(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```